# How to group matrices depending on their "similiarity"?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have `d` many matrices $M_i$ and I have a function `f` which measures how similiar those matrices are. I'm trying to group the matrices based on their similiarity, which is measured by `f`.
If $M_i$ has a similiarity to $M_j$ larger than a certain treshhold, let's say the threshold is `0.5`, then it is in the group of matrices with $M_j$.
Let's say that matrices $M_1 \text{ and } M_2$ have a similarity of `0.89`, $M_2 \text{ and } M_3$ have a similarity of `0.72` and $M_3 \text{ and } M_1$ have a similarity of `0.42`. Then, since $0.89>0.5 \text{ and } 0.72>0.5$, all matrices $M_1,M_2,M_3$ should be in one group.

Intuitively, you can think about it this way. Pretend that the matrices aren't matrices but data, for example row1 is data at time1 and so on.
The data is representing multiple processes, for example pretend that $M_1,M_2,M_3$ all describe process one, for example free-fall of a ball (then the data in the rows could be the heat, velocity or heigth of the ball). And matrices $M_4,M_5,M_6$ describe process two, for example a pendulum (the data can represent the height, accelaration or speed).
Now imagine that there is one sloppy scientist working with the data and he accidentally mixes all of the data up and lost all the labels. Now he wants to sort the data by the process they describe. Because the data has noise in it, it isn't exact and the scientist uses the similarity function `f`.
Of course there are a lot of matrices and more than two processes.
It is also important to note that the scientist is very careless and some of the matrices are just random data which won't easily be grouped. This doesn't matter so much right now, as matrices that are alone in a group or in a group with just a few other matrices will be deleted later. (I want to sort more than 50,000 matrices and I estimate, that the individual groups will have approximately 50-ish matrices.)

Comment: What if the similarity between M3 and M4 (assuming there are at least 4 matrices) is something like .8? Should M3 & M4 form a new group, leaving M1 & M2 in the previous group?

Comment: You might be able to use FindClusters. It looks like it takes a DistanceFunction option, which seems promising. I haven't used it so don't have any advice. I'd be willing to give it a try if you provide some sample data (a set of given matrices, the similarity function, and an expected output of the groupings).

Comment: You might also try Gather, but I'm not sure that it fits the kind of logic you're describing. The whole transitive similarity might be a problem.

Comment: You can also use `DistanceMatrix` on a list of matrices. It also takes a DistanceFunction option as well. It's hard to see exactly what DistanceFunction it is calculating by default for matrix inputs, so you may want to look at what it's doing first with (small) symbolic matrices.

Comment: @lericr M3 and M4 should also be in the group with M1 and M4. I will edit the question and add a intuitiv description of what im doing.

Comment: Your intuitive description doesn't help me. M3 is relatively far away from M1, but M3 is relatively close to M4, so why do you prefer {M1,M2,M3,M4} over {{M1,M2}, {M3,M4}}? Is it possible that you already know the size of each group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible approach:

```
ConnectedComponents[RelationGraph[f[#1, #2] > .5 &, {m1, m2, ...}]]
```

Comment: Note that this method does not work if there are repeated elements (e.g. `m1 == m2`).

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple $\mathcal O(N^2)$ approach*. It calculates all pairwise distances as given by the distance function, then remove all connections which are above a predefined threshold.

For simplicity, I have used numbers instead of matrices.

```
cluster[ms_, f_, threshold_] := 
 Map[ms[[#]] &, 
  ConnectedComponents[
   EdgeDelete[
    CompleteGraph[Length[ms]], (m1_ \[UndirectedEdge] m2_) /; 
     f[ms[[m1]], ms[[m2]]] <= threshold]], -2]

f[m1_, m2_] := 1 - Abs[m1 - m2];
ms = {0.2, 0.1, 1.4, 1.2, 0.0, 2.3};

cluster[ms, f, 0.5]
(* {{0.2, 0.1, 0.}, {1.4, 1.2}, {2.3}} *)
```

---

<sup>* Therefore probably unsuitable for your update with 50k elements ...</sup>

Comment: why is it unusable? Because it would take too long ?

Comment: Yes. I think you should relax your strong constraints about threshold, and just use one of the methods in `FindClusters` with `DistanceFunction`, as already proposed by @lericr.

Comment: ive already made a "correlation matrix" of the form: {{1,0},{0,1}} This means that the similiarity between M1 and M2 is 0 and the similiarity between M1 and M1 is 1 and between M2 and M2 is also 1.